# mysql and php Same query different result

Tags: php, mysql

I ran this query directly from mysql with no problem

```
"SELECT CONCAT(tgl_input, ' - ', tgl_input + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS week FROM hasil"
```

But as i ran the same query from php page

```
$query_sum = 'SELECT CONCAT(tgl_input, ' - ', tgl_input + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS week FROM hasil';
```

it return error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1.

When i try to `echo $query_sum` the result is `0`. Can anyone help me. Thank you.

Comment: If your string contains quote marks (of the same type that you use to define the string), then you need to escape them - PHP Strings 101

Comment: What you're doing here is defining your SQL query as `', tgl_input + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS week FROM hasil'` subtracted from `'SELECT CONCAT(tgl_input, '`, which will equate to `0 - 0`, or `0`

Comment: you either need to use escape the inner single quote or use double quote to wrap your query.

Comment: Thanks a million Now i can see my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes to delimit strings in PHP

```
$query_sum = "SELECT CONCAT(tgl_input,' - ',tgl_input+INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS week FROM hasil";
```

Answer (score 1):

A string that is enclosed in single quotes cannot contain a single quote, because PHP thinks the string ends there. You can solve this by escaping the quotes in your string using a backslash:

```
$query_sum = 'SELECT CONCAT(tgl_input, \' - \', tgl_input + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS week ... ';
```

Or you can use any of the other string notations to put this string in. See [PHP string types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more information about strings and their notation in PHP.

Comment: No doubt with detailed explanation.